# "Preformatted text" and Japanese

Tags: bug, furigana, formatting

This has come up before ([Preformatted text in Japanese doesn't line up properly](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1023/1628)), but at the moment, the preformatted text again doesn't line up properly for me.

What's worse is that even usual Latin text doesn't line up as soon as a single Japanese character is added. For example,

> ```
> a        b        c
> 123      456      789
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> a        b        c
> 123      456      78九
> ```

renders for me as

[image: preformatted text and Japanese]

on Linux and Android.

I don't know if we can fix this completely, but it would help immensely if adding Japanese in the last column doesn't break the alignment of the other columns.

Answer (score 2):

The root cause: **Poor CSS fonts for Japanese text**.

What has been described in the question is specific to this site. Japanese.SE uses different font choice for Latin and non-Latin (Japanese) text, which is applied via different `class` attributes (noFurigana, ja-text) specified by the stylesheet.

That is due to CSS fonts and *not* Linux specific.

### Troubleshooting

The fonts used for the preformatted text can be checked using Developer Tools provided by a web browser. For troubleshooting, follow these steps:

- While viewing this page in Firefox web browser, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> or just <kbd>F12</kbd> to toggle the developer tool.
- In the leftmost upper corner of the Developer Tools, there is an icon with square and cursor (hovering with a cursor will show "Pick an element from the page").
- Click the icon once, then hover and click on *the entire blockquote* of preformatted text in the meta question at above.
- As a result, the leftmost column will jump to the corresponding line within the HTML code of web page.

HTML code of plain Latin text (upper half):

```
<pre class="noFurigana"><code class="noFurigana">a        b        c
123      456      789
</code></pre>
```

HTML code of mixed Latin text (lower half):

```
<pre class="ja-text" lang="ja"><code class="ja-text" lang="ja">a        b        c
123      456      78<span xml:lang="ja" class="ja-text" lang="ja">九</span>
</code></pre>
```

When each block of HTML code is selected in the left column, content in the middle column will also change. Look for the content of `font-family` for respective text.

CSS fonts corresponding to plain Latin text (upper half):

```
font-family: Consolas,Menlo,Monaco,Lucida Console,Liberation Mono,DejaVu Sans Mono,Bitstream Vera Sans Mono,Courier New,monospace,sans-serif;
```

CSS fonts corresponding to mixed Latin text (lower half):

```
font-family: "IPAGothic","IPAゴシック","TakaoGothic","VL Gothic","VLゴシック","UmePlus Gothic","Ume Gothic","梅ゴシック","MotoyaLCedar","MigMix 2M","Migu 2M","Hiragino Kaku Gothic Pro","ヒラギノ角ゴ Pro W3","HiraKakuProN-W3","ヒラギノ角ゴ ProN W3","Osaka Mono","Osaka","MS Gothic","ＭＳ ゴシック","Meiryo","メイリオ",monospace !important;
```

To determine whether CSS fonts used for mixed Latin text (lower half) is the problem or not, we just need to do one more step using the Developer Tools.

### The workaround

After selecting the HTML code for mixed Latin text (class="ja-text") in the left column, bring the cursor to `font-family` section in the middle column. When hovered, a checkbox will appear on the left of section. The one more step is to **empty the checkbox for `font-family`**.

The following screenshot combo is showing before (left) and after CSS fonts is disabled in Developer Tool of Firefox.

[image: Mixed Latin text with and without the font-family]

With the workaround, the mixed Latin text will now appear aligned like the Latin text counterpart. This meta answer has clarified the said issue.